# Flutter - There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value... error with provider

Tags: flutter, provider, dropdownbutton

I have a dropdown-menu.
My goal is to let the user choose a value of the dropdown-menu.
After this the value should be shown as a list above the dropdown-menu.
I'm using Provider for storing the choosen value(s) in a List.
But when I let the List listen to the changes in the provider-model I get the error for the Dropdown-menu. I don't know why I get errors during rebuilding...

[image]

```
Provider.of<InspectionFormModel>(context, listen: true).removeAbleObjects!=null?ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      key: ObjectKey(Provider.of<InspectionFormModel>(context, listen: false).removeAbleObjects),
                      children: Provider.of<InspectionFormModel>(context, listen: false).removeAbleObjects!=null?Provider.of<InspectionFormModel>(context, listen: false).removeAbleObjects!.map((e) => e).toList():[Container()]
                    ):Visibility(child: Container(),visible: false,),
                    CustomDropdown(items: [DropDownObject("text",1),DropDownObject("textsoundso",2)], hintText: inspectionObject, provider: "inspection",value:"device",),
```

My DropDownButton:

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class CustomDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<DropDownObject> items;
  //final List<dynamic>? objects;
  final String hintText;
  final String? provider;
  final String? value;
  final bool useId;

  const CustomDropdown({Key? key,
    this.useId=false,
    this.value,
    this.provider,
    this.hintText="",
    required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomDropdown> createState() => _CustomDropdownState();
}

class _CustomDropdownState extends State<CustomDropdown> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    developer.log("init dropdown");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DropDownObject? selectedValue=null;
  


    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
        // child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButtonFormField2<DropDownObject>( 

            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null ) {
                return 'Bitte wählen Sie einen Wert aus.';
              }
              return null;
            },
            buttonHeight: 50,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              // errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)
                )
            ),//InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ""),//
            hint: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),child: Text(widget.hintText, style: AppTextStyle().formText,)),
            isExpanded: true,
            dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              border: Border.all(
                color: AppColors().grey,
              ),
            ),
            buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors().formFieldColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              border: Border.all(
                color: AppColors().grey,
              ),
            ),
            items: widget.items.map((item) =>
                DropdownMenuItem<DropDownObject>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Row(children:[
                    Expanded(child: Text(item.text, textAlign: TextAlign.left,))
                  ],)
                )).toList(),
            // value:selectedValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue=value;
                //selectedValue = value;
                //widget.useId?widget.provider??FormProviderSelection().writeValueToProviderObject(context, widget.provider!,widget.value!,selectedValue!):
                FormProviderSelection().writeValueToProviderObject(context, widget.provider!,widget.value!,value!);//widget.provider??
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded),
            iconEnabledColor: AppColors().grey,
            iconDisabledColor: Colors.white54,
            dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
            dropdownElevation: 8,
          ),
        // ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update 2022-01-22**

```
class DropDownObject{
  String text;
  int? dropDownObjectId;

  DropDownObject(this.text, [this.dropDownObjectId]);
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_button2-1.0.7/lib/dropdown_button2.dart:986:11
items == null ||
              items.isEmpty ||
              value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                    return item.value == value;
                  }).length ==
                  1
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'DropDownObject'. \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"

Comment: What are the items? Each item should be unique.

Comment: I started using non dynamic items to avoid the error coming up because of two identically items.. as you can see in my code: `CustomDropdown(items: [DropDownObject("text",1),DropDownObject("textsoundso",2)],...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have two or more same `DropDownObject`. Or you have null `DropDownObject`.

Check this part of your code.

```
items: widget.items.map((item) =>
                DropdownMenuItem<DropDownObject>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Row(children:[
                    Expanded(child: Text(item.text, textAlign: TextAlign.left,))
                  ],)
                )).toList(),
```

try to add filters:

```
widget.items
.where((e) => e != null) //removes null items
.toSet() // removes duplicate items
.map
```

also implement == and hashcode in your model class:

```
class DropDownObject{
  String text;
  int? dropDownObjectId;

  DropDownObject(this.text, [this.dropDownObjectId]);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is DropDownObject && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && text == other.text;

  @override
  int get hashCode => text.hashCode;


}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but I still get the error ...

Comment: Show your Dropdownobject class please

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: edited post. try again

Comment: thank you very much... this worked! Do I need a hashCode for all of my classes that are used in dropdown-menus?

Comment: == and hashcode is used to compare objects. Otherwise if you put same class objects to dropdownmenuitem it considers them same